# Module not found error in Python after pip install package --user

Tags: python, pip, seaborn, modulenotfounderror

I had Permission Denied error when I installed seaborn (or any libray) library (pip install seaborn - on command prompt and Jupyter notebook). I tried pip install seaborn --user and it showed that Requirements already satisfied. However, when I try to import seaborn on jupyter notebook, it returns module not found error.

Comment: Are you sure that you installed the module in the Python installation used by the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: When you're pip installing to --user you are putting the module in your home directory rather than root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably attempting to download package to a system folder where you don't have permission to write or modified, maybe it's due to modification on your `pip.ini` file which specify by default the packages location ?

Check pip documentation and his topic about configuration [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration).

Furhtermore, I advise you, if you start learning python and using pip package, to learn fundamental about the principle of **virtualenv** using **venv lib** [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). VirtualEnv is a recommended practice in python who allow you to compartmentalize project in a specified place with a personal pip package directory and other things, these methods aim to avoid dependancy concurrence between projects and also avoid pip package permissions issue by downloading pip package only for your virutalenv.

- Step by step to setup venv ( you should be in the root folder of your
  projet) :

```
user@hostname > python3 -m venv venv
user@hostname > source ./env/bin/activate
(venv) user@hostname > python -m pip install foo-packages
```

- Or the second option but not recommended is to use sudo to
  install packages to the system folder :

```
sudo@hostname > sudo python -m pip install foo-packages
```